# Possible to return number of matches per line of a regex file using `grep -f regexfile queryfile`?

Tags: unix, grep

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to transform a `grep` command such as

`grep -c -f regex.txt file.txt`

to return the total number of matched lines in `file.txt` for *each line* of `regex.txt`, instead of the sum of the matched lines found for all patterns in `regex.txt` as the above command does.

My current method of handling this is to use `xargs` (or GNU `parallel` interchangeably):

`cat regex.txt | xargs -I{} grep -c {} file.txt`

Can `grep` do this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -o -f regex.txt | sort | uniq -c
```